# NodeJS/ExpressJS: res.locals vs. session

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working with NodeJS/Express JS and have trouble understanding the difference between res.locals & sessions.
So you use sessions for say authentication and input validation of forms.
You use res.locals also for authentication and it's general purpose is that it holds data, that is always accessible in all views.

I thought sessions are also always accessible in all views.

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the res.local can be accessed from anywhere in the application. And are the same for all users.

Session variables can also be accessed from anywhere in the application, but they are different for every user. this is why you would use sessions to store a user in it and use this for authentication.